# Get HeightRequest points (RelativeLayout) by real size image via Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, screen-size, hdpi

I need to get `HeightRequest`(`RelativeLayout`) points by real size image. I get image from the server. It is size `720x250`. I need to use `RelativeLayout`.

```
<ListView
                x:Name="EventsListView"
                GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding EventGroupTitle}"
                HasUnevenRows="True"
                IsGroupingEnabled="True"
                ItemTapped="ListView_OnItemTapped"
                ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedItems}"
                SeparatorVisibility="None">
                <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
               </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell BindingContextChanged="BindableObject_OnBindingContextChanged">

                            <RelativeLayout x:Name="RelativeLayout" Padding="0">
                                <!--  Background picture  -->
                                <controls:BExtendedCachedImage
                                    x:Name="Picture"
                                    Aspect="AspectFit"
                                    CacheType="Disk"
                                    DownsampleToViewSize="True"
                                    LoadingPlaceholder="backgroundBlur"
                                    RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
                                                                                           ElementName=RelativeLayout,
                                                                                           Property=Height}"
                                    RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
                                                                                          ElementName=RelativeLayout,
                                                                                          Property=Width}"
                                    Source="{Binding Picture}" />
                            </RelativeLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

`Source="{Binding Picture}"` - my picture from the server. In code-behind in `BindableObject_OnBindingContextChanged` I need to change `HeightRequest` (`RelativeLayout`). But if I do not set the height manually, the cell will stretch to full height.

Here is my code-behind:

```
private void BindableObject_OnBindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var cell = (ViewCell) sender;
        var layout = cell.View.FindByName<RelativeLayout>("RelativeLayout");
        var bc = (GroupEventsMapPageModel) BindingContext;
        layout.HeightRequest = THIS_MANUAL_VALUE;
    }
```

How I can to get THIS_MANUAL_VALUE?

I tried via this code:

```
var device = Resolver.Resolve<IDevice>();
        var display = device.Display;
        return display.Scale;
```

Image `Height (250) \ display.Scale` - doesn't work. I create tab.

xxxhdpi device (640 dpi) - 4 (Scale)  - `layout.HeightRequest = 79;`
xxxhdpi device (560 dpi) - 3.5 (Scale)  - `layout.HeightRequest = 93;`
xhdpi device (315 dpi) - 2 (Scale)  - `layout.HeightRequest = 110;`
hdpi device (240 dpi) - 1.5 (Scale)  - `layout.HeightRequest = 165;`

However, I noticed that when changing the diagonal.

4.7" xxhdpi device (420 dpi) - 2.625 (Scale)  - `layout.HeightRequest = 87;`
5,2" xxhdpi device (420 dpi) - 2.625 (Scale)  - `layout.HeightRequest = 130;`

How can I get the formula?

Comment: This question is all over the place. What "height" are you looking for?

Comment: @ Joshua Poling, I looking for HeightRequest (Xamarin point).     For Example   <StackLayout HeightRequest="40" />

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to set the height:

```
StackLayout _mainStack = new StackLayout{ HeightRequest = 40};
```

if you're looking to get the height:

```
var _stacksHeight = _mainStack.Height;
```

The first gets or sets the desired height override for this element.
The second is a read only property to get the rendered height of _mainStack.